# Why my object based on class is not created inside event handler?

Tags: javascript

I'm making the app where you can add the book to the list visible for the site viewer and to the local storage. With first part I'm done, everything is working good:

```
// Editing User Interface
class UI {
  static addBookToTable(title, author, isbn) {
    const tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
    tableRow.innerHTML = `
      <td>${title}</td>
      <td>${author}</td>
      <td>${isbn}</td>
      <td><a href="#">X</a></td>
    `
    document.querySelector('#tableBody').appendChild(tableRow);
  }
}

// Using submit button
document.addEventListener('submit', () => {
  const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
  const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
  const isbn = document.querySelector('#isbn').value;

  UI.addBookToTable(title, author, isbn); // Adding book to visible list
})

//Using remove button
document.querySelector('#tableBody').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.tagName === "A") {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
  }
})
```

But when I work on passing the book to storage, it doesn't work. First I'm trying to create book object in submit event handler after passing the title, author, isbn variables (`book = new Book(title, author, isbn)` based on Book Class (Book Class is defined at the top of the document).

```
//Creating a Book Class
class Book {
  constructor(title, author, isbn) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
  }
}
```

Later on I'm creating this Store class

```
class Store {
  static getBooks(books){
    if (localStorage.getItem('books') === null) {
      books = [];
    } else {
      books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'))
    }
    return books;
  }

  static addBookToStore(object) {
    let books;
    Store.getBooks(books);
    books.push(object);
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
  }
}
```

But when I pass `Store.addBookToStore(book)` in submit event handler after creating the `book` object, it doesn't work. In Chrome Dev Tools console the error is showing that the `book` is finally not created becouse the functions using this object see it as undefined (here is excatly what console is displaying: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Function.addBookToStore (app.js:39) //books.push(book); from Store.addBookToStore(book)
    at HTMLDocument. (app.js:51) //Store.addBookToStore(book); //from Event Handler
). What did I do wrong? Why this object is not created inside this event handler?

Comment: `getBooks` has a `return`, but when you call `Store.getBooks` you are doing nothing with the return value. `let books = Store.getBooks()` and remove the `books` argument from `getBooks`.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the `Store` class like this:

```
class Store {
  static getBooks(){
    return localStorage.getItem('books') 
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'))
            : [];
  }

  static addBookToStore(object) {
    let books = Store.getBooks();
    books.push(object);
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
  }
}
```

Comment: What the '?' and ':' mean at the beginning of the line? Could you link me to some article or video about it? Also thank you for your answer but the problem is still not solved.

Comment: @bartekw2213 It's called [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), short hand for `if/else` statement.